# Deserialize JSON without gems or PostgreSQL in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization

I am saving a small JSON fragment in the database as follows but am stuck retrieving the data in a usable way.

In this app, Rails is getting the JSON via a fetch AJAX call, and successfully saving the following in the decor field:

```
{"drapes": "red", "table": "wood", "candles":"true"}
```

In the Rails console, this comes out as expected:

```
> p = Party.last
  => ...
> p.decor
  => "{:drapes=>\"red\", :table=>\"wood\", :candles=>\"true\"}"
```

*decor* is a (datatype) text field in SQLite at the moment. I've used PostgreSQL before for JSON but don't want to go there right now on this project and given the official doc reference (below), should be able to manage without any additional gems.

Here's the model (**party.rb**) as recommended by  https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html:

```
class Party < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :decor, JSON
end
```

And here's the relevant action in the controller (**party_controller.rb**):

```
def create
  @party = Party.new(party_params)
  @party.save
end
```

So all good until I actually want to to extract the decor and (for example) show it in a view template. With the following (in **parties/index.html.erb**)...

```
<p>
  <%= p.decor.drapes %>
</p>
```

... I get:

> NoMethodError in Parties#index
>
> undefined method `drapes'

*p.decor* is obviously coming out of the model as the wrong data type but despite various experiments in the console, I can't see how to extract the JSON values using their keys.

Comment: Yeah I had tried that in both the console and the view with no joy.

Comment: Have you checked what value is actually stored in that column/row in the database?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above, I was able to verify that p.decor is valid in the console.

Comment: Are you sure (as @matthewd says) that all the values in the `drapes` column really do contain the sort of JSON you think they do? SQLite's lax type system often works against you. The error is saying that `p.drapes` is `2` after all.

Comment: Thanks, @mu is too short. I have simplified the data from my real example to make it easier to focus on the main issue. The 2:Fixnum is probably not relevant and confusing so I have removed it from the OP.

Comment: Do like this is json ‘p.decor[“drapes”]’

Comment: So when you try `p.decor[:drapes]` in the console, what happens?

Comment: I get "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"

Comment: OK, now I can see that pulling p.decor.first.second returns "red". That's a small step forward but I really need to be able to look up a key in the JSON, not remember its position...

Comment: Thanks, @7urkm3n. You are right. I'd like to know why that works and p.decor[:drapes] doesn't, though...

Comment: Hello MSC, have you tried JSON.parse(p.decor)? (it would need " required 'json' ")

Comment: @MSC have to tried `serialize :decor, Hash`, as default serializing into json, you cant call with hash keys symbols. you have to serialize into hash or struct it.

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried Hash instead of JSON but that caused other difficulties which I wasn't keen to get into.